# javascript object sort by float-number

Tags: javascript, sorting

Hei,
I have created a js object. looks something like this

```
locationsArray.push({
          ID: receivedData[i].ID,
          Name: receivedData[i].Name,
          Distance: distance
        });
```

now I'm trying to sort this locationsArray by distance, which is a floating point number. I tried

```
function sortByKey(array, key) {
  return array.sort(function(a,b) { return a[key] - b[key];});
}
```

and I'm calling the function like this:

```
sortByKey(locationsArray, locationsArray.Distance);
```

but this does not sort properly. Here is an example output (ID, Name, Distance):

```
18, Kirjasto 10, 0.048929030237684454

1, Kuudes Linja, 0.06257994886543376

16, Café Carusel, 0.06235102244550915

15, Tavastia, 0.04540176208034692
```

I guess this is not so hard, can someone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You missed `key` from the comparator function:

```
function sortByKey(array, key) {
  return array.sort(function(a,b) { return a[key] - b[key];});
}
```

Pass in the array and the name of the field to sort by:

```
sortByKey(inputArray, 'Distance');
```

(note that `inputArray` is sorted in-place)

Comment: might be but that's definitely not helping the output.

Comment: OK. Can you post your input array and any other code you're using?

Comment: sample data is up there also I added the function call. maybe the problem is there?

Comment: The function call is the problem - the second parameter should be the property _name_. See the edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

Answer from joews is correct.
You should just change your function call to this:

```
sortByKey(locationsArray, 'Distance');
```

The key is the property name, but you are using property value instead..